# Understanding np.dot multiplication example

Tags: arrays, numpy

If

```
X = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 2],[2, 2],[2, 3]])
```

and you do `np.dot(X, np.array([1,2]))`, how does that multiply to become `array([3, 5, 6, 8])`?

I know X has a shape of `(4,2)` and the second array is `(2,)` (because it's 2 columns and it's 1D). I also know there is a special case from https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html:

```
"If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b."
```

But I can't seem to apply it correctly to get the result.

Comment: What is your expected result? Your example shows a valid dot product array, for instance 1*1+1*2=3 and so on.

Comment: In the question I meant that I was unsure of the math in getting to the answer of [3, 5, 6, 8]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [376]: X = np.array([[1, 1],[1, 2],[2, 2],[2, 3]])                                                

In [378]: y=np.array([1,2])                                                                          
In [379]: X.shape                                                                                    
Out[379]: (4, 2)
In [380]: y.shape                                                                                    
Out[380]: (2,)
```

the dot/matmul approach:

```
In [381]: X@y                                                                                        
Out[381]: array([3, 5, 6, 8])
```

`einsum` lets us specify which axes combine how:

```
In [382]: np.einsum('ij,j->i',X,y)                                                                   
Out[382]: array([3, 5, 6, 8])
```

elementwise multipication followed by sum.  The (4,2) * (2,) -> (4,2)

```
In [383]: X*y                                                                                        
Out[383]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 4],
       [2, 6]])
In [384]: (X*y).sum(1)                                                                               
Out[384]: array([3, 5, 6, 8])
```

Or by highschool math, each row of `X` times `y`, summed

```
In [386]: [sum(row*y) for row in X]                                                                  
Out[386]: [3, 5, 6, 8]
```